# all my data changed when i update only 1 data .Can anyone help to check my code?

Tags: c#

```
 protected void GridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label lblID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");
        TextBox id = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        TextBox Username = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
        TextBox Password = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
        TextBox Email = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
        GridView.EditIndex = -1;
        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update user.register set Username='" + Username.Text  + "',Email='" + Email.Text + "',Password='" + Password.Text + "',id='"+id.Text+"'",conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        Gvbind();
```

can anyone help me with it i been trying for few hour but still the same output

Comment: your sql command has no condition to limit the change to just the specific record that you want to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a WHERE clause in your update query.

You should have something like:

`WHERE ID='the id of the line you want to update'`

Answer (score 3):

Well, your query lacks a [`WHERE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) clause, which should probably look like `WHERE id = your_id`. If you miss that clause, as you have just found out, an `UPDATE` statement will update the whole table.

Also, read about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), because your code is vulnerable to that sort of attack.